# Find the branch that does not have any staff

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

Find the branch that does not have any staff

these are the 2 tables that must be used

I tried this

```
select a.branchNo,a.city 
from Branch a 
join Staff  b 
  on a.branchNo = b.branchNo 
where branchNo \<1;
```

however I know this is incorrect. The table should in the end output the branch that has no staff .

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `not exists`:

```
select b.*
from branch b
where not exists (select 1 from staff s where s.branchno = b.branchno)
```

This filters on branches that have no corresponding entry in `staff`.

We could also express this with an anti-left join (ie try to find a match, then ensure that it did not work):

```
select b.*
from branch b
left join staff s on s.branchno = b.branchno
where s.branchno is null
```